# Drawing custom candles which has non standard open times using pine scripts

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

[Pine script] I would like to draw custom candles which has custom open times, where the open times are at 00:07, 00:22, 00:37, 00:52, etc. instead of the typical 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, etc.

A15m candle stick chart can be drawn using 1m candle stick data. In that case, 1m data can be resampled, but the resampling happened with reference to the 00:00. That means the drawn candlestick chart has candles for open times 00:00, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00...etc.
But in my case I want to draw custom candles by sampling 1m data as candle sticks having open times such as 00:07, 00:22, 00:37, 00:52, .. etc.
The plotbar() or plotcandle() has no option to do that. Is there any way that can be plotted as above?

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You can draw custom candles using the `plotcandle()` function, and use some logic to calculate the OHLC values.

Here is an example of logic to use with the `plotcandle()` function you can use on a 1 minute timeframe:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

newBar = (time - (7 * 60 * 1000)) % (15 * 60 * 1000) == 0       // check if a bar time minus 7 minutes is divded by 15 minutes (all in milliseconds)
_high = ta.highest(high, 15)
_low = ta.lowest(low, 15)

candleColor = switch
    close[1] > open[14] => color.green
    => color.red

plotcandle(open[14], _high, _low, close[1], color = newBar ? candleColor : na, wickcolor = newBar ? candleColor : na)
```

The above script basically check if a bar time (measured in milliseconds) minus 7 minutes has a remainder of 0 when divided by 15 minutes. This will return `true` on each 15 minute bar offset by 7 minutes.

if the bar is `newBar` (the above is `true`) then:

1. `high` and `low` will be the highest and lowest of the last 15 bars (since we are on the 1 minute timeframe).
2. `open` will be the `open` price 14 bars ago.
3. `close` will be previous bar close.

This logic is not perfect, since that sometimes there are no trades (and therefore no bar) on the new 15 minutes timeframe, but it's the best I think can be done to achieve what you want.